# Update widget with data from another Python process, without blocking it

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, ipc, qdialog

I'm running a Python script that extracts and localizes some files. I'd like to use a `QDialog` to show the progress status through a `QProgressBar`, and the list of files that are being copied.

Let me start by saying that the localization script cannot be integrated in the PyQt script - otherwise I'm aware that the solution would be quite straightforward. I need to keep the localization script separated from the UI and have them running at the same time.

I thought about running the UI from the localization script through a thread, to avoid it blocking the localization process. But at that point I have no idea how to update the UI elements as I don't have an instance I can call and update since I've launched it with the thread.

This is a simplified example of the dialog code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_dialog_main(object):

    def setupUi(self, dialog_main):
        dialog_main.setWindowTitle("Test")
        dialog_main.resize(390, 120)

        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(dialog_main)
        self.progress_bar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 371, 30))

        self.label_localizing = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog_main)
        self.label_localizing.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 81, 25))
        self.label_localizing.setText("Package:")

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_main)


def start():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_main = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_dialog_main()
    ui.setupUi(dialog_main)
    dialog_main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is how I'm starting the thread in the localizer file:

```
thread = Thread(target=LocManager.start)
thread.start()
```

where `LocManager` is the name of the ui .py file.

Of course this way the main script doesn't get stuck by the ui, which is one of my goals - but I have no idea how to update the progress bar and label in this situation. I've found several threads discussing similar problems, but nothing that would exactly help with mine.

I hope my description was clear enough.

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution for this [here](https://gist.github.com/mottosso/a779958135b3659d639a), using pipes. Even if I'm not sure this is the appropriate way to tackle this issue, it definitely did the trick. Instead of working with a "Bi-directional Communication" between two PyQt GUIs, as described in the link, I modified the code to have a bi-directional communication between my GUI and my localization script.

Comment: In `thread = Thread(target=LocManager.start)`, target should be the name of a function not a `.py` file

Comment: @nathancy it is the name of a function indeed. it's the 'def start():' i'm defining in the first chunk of code. By the way, that code is working. My problem is updating the UI I created with those lines once the thread is running.

Comment: @Izzy88 As indicated in my answer, the problem is that you are running the GUI in another thread and that is forbidden, you must do the reverse: the copy task must be executed in the other thread, if you provide a [mcve] we could help you more

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the copy task starts before everything else and there's no way to do otherwise. I was just hoping in a solution that didn't involve changing the logic/order in which my processes are called. Therefore it wouldn't make any sense to give additional minimal examples as the minimal example is already there. As you said, what I'm trying to do is not allowed so I'll stick to the documentation. thanks

Comment: @Izzy88 Exactly, unfortunately you will have to change your logic.

Comment: @Izzy88 Are you still interested in a solution for this? It can be achieved without multi-threading.

Comment: @ekhumoro hi, I've just updated my question with the solution I found, which is working. If you have a more functional solution I'm all ears.

Comment: @Izzy88 Do you reallly need two-way communication? Your question only asks for one-way. I have posted an an answer that assumes on-way in order to keep things simple. The code could be even simpler without all the error handling - but it is still quite starightforward. There is no use of multi-threading at all.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to run the dialog in a separate process, and then use some form of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to send the updates. The solution below uses Qt's `QLocalServer` and `QLocalSocket` classes to pass a `dict` encoded with json to the dialog process. The server emits a signal whenever new data is received, which the dialog connects to in order to process updates. When the sending process exits, the server process is automatically shut down.

**test.py**:

```
import time
from dlg_server import send_data

for message in 'One Two Three Four Five'.split():
    send_data(message=message)
    time.sleep(2)
```

**dlg_server.py**:

```
import sys, os, json, atexit
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

SERVER = 'dlg_server'
_tries = 0

def send_data(**data):
    socket = QtNetwork.QLocalSocket()
    socket.connectToServer(SERVER, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    if socket.waitForConnected(500):
        socket.write(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
        if not socket.waitForBytesWritten(2000):
            raise RuntimeError('could not write to socket: %s' %
                  socket.errorString())
        socket.disconnectFromServer()
    elif socket.error() == QtNetwork.QAbstractSocket.HostNotFoundError:
        global _tries
        if _tries < 10:
            if not _tries:
                if QtCore.QProcess.startDetached(
                    'python', [os.path.abspath(__file__)]):
                    atexit.register(lambda: send_data(shutdown=True))
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError('could not start dialog server')
            _tries += 1
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)
            send_data(**data)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('could not connect to server: %s' %
                socket.errorString())
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('could not send data: %s' % socket.errorString())


class Server(QtNetwork.QLocalServer):
    dataReceived = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.newConnection.connect(self.handleConnection)
        if not self.listen(SERVER):
            raise RuntimeError(self.errorString())

    def handleConnection(self):
        data = {}
        socket = self.nextPendingConnection()
        if socket is not None:
            if socket.waitForReadyRead(2000):
                data = json.loads(str(socket.readAll().data(), 'utf-8'))
                socket.disconnectFromServer()
            socket.deleteLater()
        if 'shutdown' in data:
            self.close()
            self.removeServer(self.fullServerName())
            QtWidgets.qApp.quit()
        else:
            self.dataReceived.emit(data)


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 30)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def handleDataReceived(self, data):
        self.show()
        self.label.setText(data.get('message', ''))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    server = Server()
    server.dataReceived.connect(dialog.handleDataReceived)
    app.exec_()
```